# System.FormatException when trying to convert String to Double

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I got this error when I'm trying to convert String into Double on WP7 C#.

```
tokenvalue = Convert.ToDouble(saParsed[i].Replace(".", ","));
```

I getting this error in WP7.
A first chance exception of type `System.FormatException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`

Is there any way to avoid it or is it only a fault of Emulator?

Comment: What is the value of the string at `saParsed[i]`?

Comment: Can you Show us the String Value's ?? And Use `TryParse` for better error handling

Comment: Instead of replacing ./, it is always better to spec the CultureInfo.

Comment: saParsed[i] can be for example 4.1
CultureInfo didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

First you can try to use this:

```
double tokenvalue = Convert.ToDouble(saParsed[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Anyway you'd better check if it's ok:

```
double tokenvalue;
if (Double.TryParse(saParsed[i], out tokenvalue) 
{ 
    // Do what you please here
}
```

Comment: saParsed[i] can be for example 4.0 or 4.1

Comment: OK, I tried and nothing helped. This class is the implementation of Shunting-yard algorithm. It works on Console Application but on WP7 I'm getting this error.

Comment: @user1138470: which language has emulator? Which is locale?

Comment: Emulator language is English(US), the same as locale.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
var tokenvalue = Convert.ToDouble(saParsed[i]);
var tokenValueText = tokenValue.ToString().Replace(".", ",");
```

Hope it will work fine if saParsed[i] is holding the valid double value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it with the following statement:

```
double tokenvalue; 
if (double.TryParse(saParsed[i], NumberStyles.Any, 
    NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out tokenvalue))
{  
    // Convertion was successfull
}
```